# How to add a new item to a to-do list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I am coding a form and a part of it requires adding new items to a to-do list named 'list of works'. The issue seems to be in my JavaScript. I am a total beginner and I have done my best but it is not working. I would appreciate any help. Attached is the link to my code https://plnkr.co/edit/QznPAo7ucKBN8xJF.

```js
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);

  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
/* the box containg the 'new project' form */

.box {
  border: none;
  padding: 4%;
  background-color: #FAEC31;
  border-radius: 4%;
}


/* the styling of text in the form */

.form-content {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.addBtn {
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #FAD626;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20%;
  border-color: #FAD626;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #F2F6F8;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="form-content">
    <form>
      <h2>Project information</h2>
      <label for="works-list">List of works:</label>
      <div id="myDIV" class="header">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
        <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
      </div>
      <ul id="myUL">
        <li>to do 1</li>
        <li>to do 2</li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this [repo](https://github.com/developedbyed/vanilla-todo) will help you. This is **todo app** in vanilla JavaScript

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with `li`. E.g. `document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);`

Comment: What's the meaning of appending "\u00D7" to the TODO items?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the item to the list. Retrieve the `UL` element and append the `LI` one to it:

```
  // [...]
  li.appendChild(span);
  // UL retrieval 
  var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  // LI appending
  ul.appendChild(li);
```

---

**Working snippet:**

```js
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);

  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
  var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
/* the box containg the 'new project' form */

.box {
  border: none;
  padding: 4%;
  background-color: #FAEC31;
  border-radius: 4%;
}


/* the styling of text in the form */

.form-content {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.addBtn {
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: #FAD626;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20%;
  border-color: #FAD626;
}

.addBtn:hover {
  background-color: #F2F6F8;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="form-content">
    <form>
      <h2>Project information</h2>
      <label for="works-list">List of works:</label>
      <div id="myDIV" class="header">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
        <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
      </div>
      <ul id="myUL">
        <li>to do 1</li>
        <li>to do 2</li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing getting the list and adding items to it with what you already created. Also, in your online sample, you are using `<script>` tags within your **.js** and that's a mistake, just get rid of them.

```
function newElement() {
  var list = document.getElementById('myUL');
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);

  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode character ×, or U+00D7, is known as the "Multiplication Sign". It is for the x logo, or close button to hide the todolist that closed

Comment: This should be a comment because it is an answer to the comment and not the question.